# django rest framework - cannot get the class based view right

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here is my codes:

## serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ( 'username', 'email')


class AllListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ('name', 'desc', 'thumbnail', 'office_no', 'mobile_no', 'email', 'web ')
```

## views.py

```
class UserViewSet(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class AllListing(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Listing.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AllListingSerializer
```

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                        url(r'^$', apiview.UserViewSet),
                        url(r'^listings/$', apiview.AllListing),
                        )
```

But when i goto the base url it shows

> **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

and when i goto '/listings/' url, it give me 404 Page Not Found, but I have few listings in the db.

I am pretty new in django. I can't figure out what wrong with them. I am using Django 1.7.1 in virtualwrappr, python 3.4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should call [`.as_view()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view) for each API view:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^$', apiview.UserViewSet.as_view()),
                       url(r'^listings/$', apiview.AllListing.as_view()),
                      )
```

Also, consider using REST framework's [`Routers`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers) which *provide you with a simple, quick and consistent way of wiring your view logic to a set of URLs*.

Comment: But when I try with Routers, it give me `as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` error.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me when I extended `generics.GenericAPIView` in stead of `viewsets.GenericViewSet` in my custom `ViewSet` class.

Pretty obvious but easy to miss.